# CTC Annual History as a Pivot Table sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table looks like below

```
select * from Salary_hist

EMPNAME CTC     DateAdded
===========================
Ram    300000   2015-01-01
Ram    30000    2014-01-01
Ram    3000     2013-01-02
Ram    2700     2013-01-01
Ram    300      2012-01-01
Ram    30       2011-01-01
```

I am trying to make the output to show History increase for all employee based on Max Salary for a particular year

Output like

```
EMPNAME 2015    2014    2013    2012    2011    
============================================
Ram    300000   30000   3000   300     30
```

Tried two method using rank and Alias but seems missing some thing.

```
select

Y.EMPNAME,
       year(Y.DateAdded),
       year(y.DateAdded)-2,
       year(y.DateAdded)-3,
      year(y.DateAdded)-4,
      year(y.DateAdded)-5
       from (
select X.EMPNAME,
       max(case when rn = 1 then CTC end) as dateadded,
       max(case when rn = 2 then CTC end) as dateadded1,
       max(case when rn = 3 then CTC end) as dateadded2,
       max(case when rn = 4 then CTC end) as dateadded3,
       max(case when rn = 5 then CTC end) as dateadded4
from
(
select row_number() over (partition by empname order by dateadded desc) as rn,
       empname,
       CTC,
       Dateadded
  from Salary_hist
) X group by EMPNAME,dateadded)
 y
```

And

```
select  EMPNAME,
  max(case when DatePart(Year, dateadded) = DatePart(Year, GETDATE()) then CTC end) as dateadded,
  max(case when DatePart(Year, dateadded) = DatePart(Year, GETDATE()-1) then CTC end) as dateadded-1,
  max(case when DatePart(Year, dateadded) = DatePart(Year, GETDATE()-2) then CTC end) as dateadded-2,
  max(case when DatePart(Year, dateadded) = DatePart(Year, GETDATE()-3) then CTC end) as dateadded-3,
  max(case when DatePart(Year, dateadded) = DatePart(Year, GETDATE()-4 ) then CTC end) as dateadded-4,
  max(case when DatePart(Year, dateadded) = DatePart(Year, GETDATE()-5) then CTC end) as dateadded-5
from  Salary_hist
group by EMPNAME, dateadded)
```

Comment: With this data you probably don't notice what happens if a certain person doesn't have a salary increase during the year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in a much simple way using `MAX` with `PARTITION BY` and taking `DISTINCT` on it. You doesn't need a **Sub-query** here.

**1. STATIC PIVOT**

You can use this when the value of `year` is known in advance.

```
SELECT EMPNAME,[2015],[2014],[2013],[2012],[2011]
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT EMPNAME,MAX(CTC) OVER(PARTITION BY EMPNAME,YEAR(DATEADDED))MAXCTC,
    YEAR(DATEADDED)PERIOD
    FROM #TEMP
)S
PIVOT
(
    MIN(MAXCTC)
    FOR PERIOD IN([2015],[2014],[2013],[2012],[2011])
)P
```

- **[Click here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/281314/static-pivot) to view result**

**2. Dynamic pivot**

You can use this if the values of `year` is unknown in advance.

```
DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @cols = COALESCE (@cols + ',[' + YEAR + ']', '[' + YEAR + ']')
               FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT CAST(YEAR(DATEADDED)AS VARCHAR(4)) [YEAR] FROM #TEMP) PV 
               ORDER BY CAST([YEAR] AS INT) DESC
               
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM 
             (
                SELECT DISTINCT EMPNAME,MAX(CTC) OVER(PARTITION BY EMPNAME,YEAR(DATEADDED))MAXCTC,
                YEAR(DATEADDED)PERIOD
                FROM #TEMP
             ) x
             PIVOT 
             (
                 MIN(MAXCTC)
                 FOR PERIOD IN (' + @cols + ')
            ) p
            ORDER BY EMPNAME;' 

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @query
```

- **[Click here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/281317/dynamic-pivot-with-year-as-column) to view result**

Answer (score 0):

With that kind of table structure making a select that returns start salary of the year in case there is no salary increase for that year and otherwise returns the max. salary makes it slightly more complex:

```
select
  empname, [2011], [2012], [2013], [2014], [2015]
from 
  (
    select
      empname,
      year(dateAdded) as year,
      max(CTC) as CTC
    from
      salary_hist S
    group by
      empname,
      year(dateAdded)

    union all

    select
      S.empname,
      Y.Year,
      S.CTC
    from
      (select distinct year(DateAdded) as Year from Salary_hist) Y
      outer apply (
        select S.empname, S.CTC, 
        row_number() over 
          (partition by empname order by DateAdded desc) as RN
        from Salary_Hist S
        where DateAdded 
          <= convert(datetime, convert(varchar, Y.Year) + '0101', 112)
      ) S
    where
      S.RN = 1
  ) as S
  pivot (
    max (CTC) for year in ([2011],[2012],[2013],[2014],[2015])
  ) as P
```